# How to make face recognition for attendance using Cordova?

Tags: cordova, curl, lumen, face-recognition

I have a trouble how to implement face recognition on cordova. I want user take a photo from the apps and then send it to the API for the face recognition process, but I have no idea where to start working on the API. I have create the apps using cordova it can access the camera smartphone and take user location. Now I'm stuck in face recognition process. I have tried using ibm watson visual-recognition, but I'm still doesn't know how to use it.

I'm sorry if it hard to understand my question, english is not my first language. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/lnsoft/cordova-plugin-lnsoft-facerecognition BTW, how is your Chinese?

Comment: well, my chinese are bad too.

Comment: But thanks for the reference, I'll try using google translate to read it.